# Return color on hover

Tags: html, css

Here I created 3 images that goes from color to grayscale and I want to show the color on hover what I've done wrong?

Here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/4tHWg/6/

CSS code:

```
 .box {
       float: left;
       position: relative;
       width: 14.285714286%;
 }
  
 .boxInner img {
       width: 100%;
       display: block;
 }

 .boxInner img:hover {
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes toGrayScale {
    to { -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);  }
 }

 .box:nth-child(1) img {
    -webkit-animation: toGrayScale 1s 0.5s forwards;
 }

.box:nth-child(2) img {
    -webkit-animation: toGrayScale 2s 1s forwards;
}

.box:nth-child(3) img {
    -webkit-animation: toGrayScale 3s 1.5s forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another simple solution for that.

```
.grayscale {
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
filter: gray;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);}

.grayscale:hover {
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create another webkit animation for off the greyscale.

```
@-webkit-keyframes offGrayScale {
to {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  }
}
```

Than you create the hover (for each img)

```
.box:nth-child(1) img:hover {
-webkit-animation: offGrayScale 1s 0.5s forwards;}
.box:nth-child(2) img:hover {
-webkit-animation: offGrayScale 1s 0.5s forwards;}
.box:nth-child(3) img:hover {
-webkit-animation: offGrayScale 1s 0.5s forwards;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/valentinzaraf/Ggqy6/